# Android Studio InstrumentationTestCase Configuration and Log Output

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, logcat, android-testing

I'm new to Android development and just experimented with unit testing inside Android Studio.  I have 2 questions,

1. each time I need to run tests I need to create a "Run/Debug Configurations" for the test class that derives from InstrumentationTestCase, and in this configuration I can only specify 1 test class and 1 test method at a time. Is there a way to break this limitation so I can run a bunch of test classes and their test methods altogether?
2. I have Log statements in my tests, but I could not find where it logged the output messages to, I checked logcat and event log but didn't find it there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should be able to right/control click either a test method, or a test class (suite) and run the test from the context menu.

After you run it once, the run config should be, permanently, in the list of runnable configurations, and available in all of the handy ways.

2) The most likely reason that your log messages are not showing up, is that Studio has this annoying habit of automatically installing a filter, on a run, so that it only shows log messages that are from the package of the app you are running.  Since your test and your app are in different packages, it is probably filtering some of the messages away.

Comment: +1 Thanks Blake. Ya I see them now, basically I put my tests into its own package like com.example.app.tests, but the filters dropdown for some reason does not include my "tests" package as an option.  As soon as I moved the tests back to com.example.app, it's shown.